# В чем отличие Visual Studio 2010 и Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#

В чем отличие Visual Studio 2010 и Visual Studio 2017.
Есть хоть какое-то отличие, может там C# новее или что-то другое. Просто у моего друга стоит VS 17 и у него работает программа, та, которая у меня не работает на VS 10.

Comment: да, там  точно нове .NET и, соответственно, версии C#. Если бы Вы показали текст ошибки, или саму программу, Вам бы больше рассказали бы.

Comment: Навигация в контексте.
Понимание кода.
Быстрое устранение ошибок.
Все неполадки в списке ошибок.
Легко выполняйте рефакторинг.
и не только см. тут https://www.visualstudio.com/ru/vs/features/ide/

Comment: Да. Кардинально отличается. Опишите ошибки, прикрепите скриншоты и код и мжет Мы сможем Вам помочь запустить программу

Comment: Тормозами ещё отличается.. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если судить по [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio), то VS 10 не предназначен для проектов, которые написаны выше .NET 4 версии (то есть его основные версии, это 2.0 — 4.0).

Приведу таблицу с Вики:

> Visual Studio .NET (2002) > 1.0
>   Visual Studio .NET 2003 > 1.1
>   Visual Studio 2005 > 3.0
>   Visual Studio 2008 > 2.0, 3.0, 3.5
>   Visual Studio 2010 > 2.0 — 4.0
>   Visual Studio 2012 > 2.0 — 4.5.2
>   Visual Studio 2013 > 2.0 — 4.5.2
>   Visual Studio 2015 > 2.0 — 4.6
>   Visual Studio 2017 > 2.0 — 4.6.2; Core 1.0

---

Также нашел [ответ модератора](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1601fdf4-ef6a-4d5e-873b-e771e389388c/how-to-use-visual-studio-2010-for-developing-net-46-applications?forum=visualstudiogeneral):

> VS 2010 couldn't target .NET Framework 4.6.
>   So you may still need to use VS 2012 or more advanced edition to build your project.

Так что вердикт прост - Из коробки, VS 10 не поддерживает проекты, которые написаны на .NET выше 4 версии. Может и есть способы борьбы с этим, но честно, на дворе 2018 год, а вы используете инструментарий, который в свое время даже и не знал, что будет .NET 4.6++, C# 7++ и многое другое, что дало разработчикам кучу нового и полезного! Вы же в свою очередь используете старого динозавра, которого давно пока положить на полку истории и забыть. Совет, обновитесь и используйте новейшие версии для разработки своего ПО.

Comment: А если обновление требует приобретения нового компьютера, затем переноса на него всего программного обеспечения, настроек, процессов, рабочих процессов, борьбы с тем, что отвалилось и не может работать, как раньше? Кто заплатит за всё это, за потраченное на это время, за отмену вложений, сделанных ранее? Ценность работающего много выше ценности нового. Если новое требует отказаться от работающего и остаться с проблемой, зачем оно вообще? Чтобы потешить разработчиков, ищущих себе, чем бы заняться и как выразить себя?

Comment: @AlekseyF. Это крик души, который нацелен на разжигание дискуссии тут? Если да, то извините, я не из тех, кто любит поспорить. Ну а так, удачной вам работы с асинхронностью и потоками на старой студии, которая поддерживает только .NET fw 4. Удачи с машинным обучением. Удачи вообще с чистотой кода, ведь то, что раньше на .NET fw 4 писалось в 100 строк кода, на современном .NET6 пишется в одну. И это я еще молчу про производительность, например Web запросы, в .NET6 сильно измененный `HttpClient`, который значительно быстрее все обрабатывает, а в .NET fw 4 `HttpWebRequest`, признанный устаревшим.

Comment: EvgeniyZ, при чём тут крик души? Это совершенно практический вопрос. Вот вы цените свои трудозатраты: вам важно решать меньшим количеством строк кода больше задач. Почему вы отказываете в этом всем пользователям? Почему вы не цените их трудозатраты? Ваш ответ сводится к отказу от ответственности за создание и решение вопроса трудозатрат. Вам никто не запрещает применять какие-угодно новшества, пока это не означает напрячь ради этого ВСЕХ пользователей. Пользователям без разницы, на сколько вам легче работать с многопоточностью, что там с чистотой кода и всеми остальными вашими "ценностями".

Answer (score 0):

Да. Кардинально отличается. Поддержка версий языка, .net фреймворка, дебагер... да все уже успело поменяться. Опишите ошибки, прикрепите скриншоты и код и может Мы сможем Вам помочь запустить программу. Но лучше всего это использовать новую версию студии. Лично я думаю что сейчас не приемлемо использовать ниже 2015.. и если есть возможность я бы и ее не рекомендовал ставить, а только свежайшие, стабильные обновления.